# Find the lonely integer in an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

Please refer to [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lonely-integer) hackerrank challenge if you can.

The problem  is to find the lonely integer in an array, given an array consists of only pairs except one lonely integer.

The problem is with this test case

```
9
4 9 95 93 57 4 57 93 9
```

9 is array size and below is the array

See the part of code highlighted by //------

If I place `scanf("%d", &n)` above `int arr[n]`, the code works fine, but it gives horrible results the other way round.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int lonely_integer(int* a, int size);

int main(){
    //n is size of array, i is counter variable
    int n, i, result;
    // ---------------------
    int arr[n];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // ---------------------
    printf("%d\n", n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    result = lonely_integer(arr, n);
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}


int lonely_integer(int* a, int size){
    int i;
    int res = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        res = res ^ a[i];
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: How can it know how large the array should be (i.e. what "n" is) before "n" is initialized?

Comment: But why is it working for 3 test cases out of 4?

Comment: Please just think about this yourself: `int arr[n];
    scanf("%d", &n);` You define an array of size n and n has the value [nothing here], and then you scan the size... (BTW: If you have to write comments like: `//n is size of array, i is counter variable` then your variable names aren't meaningful enough, change them to something like `counter and size or arraySize`)

Comment: If buggy code passes some tests, it means nothing. Buggy code in C is very unpredictable. It's quite possible for the software to pass all your tests but then, when you run it on your boss' computer, it can decide to delete all your boss' files. If a test fails, it tells you something; but if a test passes, it tells you nothing.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to store the integers in an array? You can just do the computation on the integers one at a time as you read them, potentially saving you a lot of memory and always saving you the complication of allocating the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
/* ... */
int *arr;
scanf("%d", &n);
arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

This way, `arr` gets dynamically allocated at runtime, so it can be of any size depending on the input `n`.

What you were originally doing (i.e. declaring `arr[n]` after recieving `n` via scanf: `scanf("%d", &n); int arr[n];`) is not a good idea because it makes use of **Variable-Length Arrays**, a feature of C that is not mandatory in the latest C standard.

You see, `arr` gets created at compile-time, and you *normally* can only initialize it with a constant expression known at compile-time, which `n`, a variable recieved as user input, obviously isn't. Variable-length arrays are a feature of the language that basically allows you to bypass this rule, i.e. they make you able to initialize an array to a length not known at compile-time. This has been standartized in **C99**, but was listed as "optional" as of **C11**.

What you did after that (`int arr[n]; scanf("%d", &n);`) is quite illogical because, well, you declare `arr` as an array of `n` integers *before* you recieve the value of `n` as user input, and, well, know its value. It prints garbage because `n` is originally initialized to an unspecified "garbage" value, and this is what your VLA's size becomes when you declare it:

```
int arr[n]; //n is garbage at this point, you have no idea how large arr will be!
scanf("%d", &n); //you got the value of n that you needed, but too late, alas!
```

Answer (score 2):

Range of `n` is given in the question is `1 <= N < 100` which is small and a [variable length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) can be used. But you are doing wrong here

```
int arr[n];   // n is uninitialized. Its value is indeterminate.
scanf("%d", &n);
```

You need to initialize `n` before using it as array size

```
scanf("%d", &n);
int arr[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocating array with a uninitialized variable, will lead to undefined behavior and the compiler will throw a warning "variable used uninitialized in this function"

If you are getting the size of array at runtime, it would be wise to use dynamic memory allocation as @Mints97 posted

```
int data_size;
int *data_array;
scanf("%d", &data_size);
data_array = (int*)calloc(data_size,sizeof(int));
/*
 .
*/
// Free the memory at the end
free(data_array);
data_array = NULL;
```

If you want to set size of array at compile time, you can define a macro

```
#define DATA_SIZE 9
```

or set the macro while compiling the code

```
gcc test.c -o test -DDATA_SIZE=9 -Wall
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of 'n' has to be defined before it has used.like you are using

int arr[n];

before reading the value of 'n'. So compiler will not know, how many number of elements are present in the array 'n' can be a garbage value.how much amount of memory it should allocate to an array.

hence you gotta read the value of 'n' before using it an array definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kotlin. Group all items and get their number with eachCount method. It will return a Map<element, Int>. If we know there will be only 1 unique element. we can take first or last element of keys of map.

```js
 
fun lonelyinteger(a: Array<Int>): Int {
        return a.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().filter { it.value==1 }.keys.first()
    }
```

Comment: The question was not how to solve the coding puzzle, it was about why provided **C** code would have an undefined behaviour. Providing an answer using existing libraries in another language will not help the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

For a maximum of 100 elements, there is no need to dynamically allocate an array (either through malloc or using a VLA). Just create an array of 100 elements.

Then you only need to *use* N elements.

```
  int arr[100];  // input will be 1..100 elements

  int size;
  scanf( "%d", &size );  // input is in 1..99

  for (int i = 0;  i < size;  i++)
    scanf( "%d", &arr[i] );
```

Looking at your solution, though, why bother with an array? Just compute the lonely integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_int(void)
{
  int d;
  scanf( "%d", &n );
  return d;
}

int main(void)
{
  int n = get_int();

  int lonely = 0;
  while (n --> 0)
    lonely ^= get_int();

  printf( "%d\n", lonely );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function lonelyInteger(a){
 let n = [1,2,3,4,3,2,1];
 let unique = a.filter(function(value){
 return a.indexOf(value) === a.lastindexOf(value)
 })
 retun unique[0]
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question was specifically about C. This is not C, so this does not answer the question.