# XOR operation returning only non-pair element in integer array

Tags: arrays, xor

I came across this problem while solving challenges on Hackerrank.

```
/*
Problem Statement

There are N integers in an array A. All but one integer occur in pairs. Your task is to find the number that occurs only once.

Input Format

The first line of the input contains an integer N, indicating the number of integers. The next line contains N space-separated integers that form the array A.

Constraints

1≤N<100 
N % 2=1 (N is an odd number) 
0≤A[i]≤100,∀i∈[1,N]
Output Format

Output S, the number that occurs only once.
*/
```

The normal solution which I would write in this case turned out to be extremely complicated, with lots of nested if loops. On searching a bit, I found this solution which solves the problem by simply XOR-ing all the elements in the integer array with each other, and the result is the lonely integer.

Here's the related method (main() method which accepts input and parses it into integer array not shown as it's not relevant here) :

```
    static int lonelyinteger(int[] a) {

        int n = a.length;
        int result = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result = result ^ a[i];
        }

        return  result;

}
```

I am not sure how this XOR operation is able to return the "lonely integer" in the array. I'm aware of the two properties of XOR, as:

```
 1. a^a=0
 2. a^0=a
```

But other than this, I couldn't quite figure out how XOR worked here.

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264936/find-the-lonely-integer-in-an-array) on SO with the same content, but that asks a different question, so I had to ask this (again).

I'd highly appreciate if anyone could provide a detailed explanation for this XOR operation.

Answer (score 5):

Since `a^a` is equal to 0 for any `a`, all of the matching pairs of integers will cancel each other out, leaving 0. That is then XOR'ed with the final number. Since `0^a` is equal to `a` for any `a`, the result will be that final number.
Simple demo:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6].reduce :^'
4
```

You can see why this works if you go through the individual pairs:

```
1 ^ 1 = 0 
0 ^ 2 = 2
2 ^ 2 = 0
0 ^ 3 = 3
3 ^ 3 = 0
0 ^ 4 = 4
4 ^ 5 = 1
1 ^ 5 = 4
4 ^ 6 = 2
2 ^ 6 = 4
```

The result toggles between 0 and the latest number until you get to the loner; after that it toggles between that number and... whatever you get when you XOR it with the latest new number.  The actual value there doesn't matter because it will be zapped when you XOR in the second copy of that number, and you're back to the copy of the singleton.

I sorted the numbers to make it easy to spot the singleton, but since XOR undoes itself, the order doesn't matter at all:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts [6,3,4,1,1,2,2,6,3,5,5].reduce :^'
4
```

6 ^ 3 is ... some number, and then that number ^ 4 is some other number, and then you XOR that with 1, and none of that matters because then you undo the 1, and then you throw in another intermediate result with the 2 and undo it right away, and then you undo the 6 and the 3, so you're back to just the 4.  Which you XOR with 5 to get another ephemeral number that is then washed away by the final 5, leaving, once again, 4.